# GetAllActorsWithTag fails if I don't delay for atleast 0.5 seconds?

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I was trying to get an actor by its tag in a BeginPlay function on another object. The tag is already set in the level and it is the correct one because I can get it to successfully find it but, for some reason there has to be a 0.5 second delay before it will detect the object in question. Is there a reason this might happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `BeginPlay` that you are trying to get actors? `GameMode` or `PlayerController`? You can try to get actors in `StartPlay` which can be overrided in `GameMode`, `StartPlay` triggled after `BeginPlay` executed.